# Can WSO2 Identity Server be integrated with an existing CAS framework?

Tags: wso2

I am experimenting with WSO2 API Manager and would like to integrate the embedded WSO2 Identity Server with our institutions existing CAS framework. Is it possible to have the WSO2 Identity Server redirect logins to our CAS login page and use the CAS ticket in place of username/password?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-enable-sso-for-wso2-server.html) explains how to use WSO2 IS as identity server for WSO2 products such as WSO2 AS, ESB etc.
You can configure your CAS instead of WSO2 IS in the very much similar way.